# Ionic Popup blocking ng-click in ionic modal

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

Plunkr: [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zJPSd0X2dh0aRnnnYKXS?p=preview)

I have a plunker as following. There are 2 ways that i show the `ionic modal`: 
1) Click on the button to show ionic modal directly. 
2) Click on the button to show ionic popup, follow by click on another button to show ionic modal.

Note that in situation (1), I can close the ionic modal by clicking on top left button but not in case of situation (2).

Note: 
1) the ionic popup should remain when the ionic modal is open in (2) 
2) `backDropClickToClose` must set to false.

To make the ionic modal above ionic popup, I have use following css:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 13 !important;
}
```

My suspect is that some css is blocking the modal open in (2) from being clicked. Maybe some sort of `z-index`. Hope someone can help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery plugin in index.html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In controller.js add a line to remove popup-open class.

```
$scope.showPopup = function() {
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '',
    title: 'Popup',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Cancel' },
      {
        text: '<b>Show Modal Dialog</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {
          $('body').removeClass('popup-open');
          $scope.openModal();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
};
```

Replace closeModal  function in controller.js with below code.

```
$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
```

Comment: By removing e.preventDefault() the ionic popup will be closed and i dun want that to happen as mentioned in my post nor do i looking for reinitialising the ionic popup when closing the modal dialog

Comment: Include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in index.html file

IN controller , For popup add a line to remove popup-open class from body
onTap: function(e) {
          $('body').removeClass('popup-open');
          $scope.openModal();
          e.preventDefault();
        }

In closemodal function , add use  this

$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };